# What is the equivalent of curve_fit's popt in lmfit?

Tags: python, lmfit

I want to use my fit from lmfit to generate data points. I can do it with the popt output from curve_fit. What is the equivalent from lmfit?

I tried it with curve_fit, and that works well. However, the fit from lmfit is better and I would like to use it. But I just don't know how?

With curve_fit:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def _1gaussian(x, amp1,cen1,sigma1):
"""By Emily Grace Ripka: https://github.com/emilyripka/BlogRepo/blob/master/181119_PeakFitting.ipynb"""
    return amp1*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp(-((x-cen1)**2)/((2*sigma1)**2)))

function_mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - function_mean) ** 2) / sum(y))
p0 = [max(y), function_mean, sigma]
popt,pcov = curve_fit(_1gaussian, x, y, p0)

new_x = np.linspace(int(min(x)), int(max(x)), 100)
new_y = _1gaussian(new_x, *popt)
```

With lmfit:

```
from lmfit.models import PseudoVoigtModel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mod = PseudoVoigtModel()
pars = mod.guess(y, x=x)
out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, out.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a single, direct analog of `popt`, but there are a few options to get the values of the variable parameters that reflect that parameters are named and ordered.  You might try:

```
>>> print(out.best_values)

{'fraction': 0.2553102387885937, 'sigma': 0.7979269636290158, 'center': 5.659382353179054, 'amplitude': 9.539383879170684}
```

or

```
>>> for name, par in out.params.items():
...     print("{:s} = {:.4f} +/- {:.4f}".format(name, par.value, par.stderr))

fraction = 0.2553 +/- 0.0683
sigma = 0.7979 +/- 0.0143
center = 5.6594 +/- 0.0097
amplitude = 9.5394 +/- 0.2142
fwhm = 1.5959 +/- 0.0285
height = 5.1534 +/- 0.0679
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intensitycalc.py", line 172, in <module>
    for name, par in out.params.values():
TypeError: 'Parameter' object is not iterable

But it works if I only use:

    for par in out.params.values():
        print(par.value)

Comment: fixed to be `for name, par in out.params.items():`